# Upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 broke my system

Tags: dual-boot, upgrade, updates

Last night my Ubuntu 20.04 System updater asked me if I wanted to upgrade to 22.04. It was a good time, so I went ahead with it. Everything seemed to be working fine, and it was installed properly. When it was the time to restart. I clicked restart and when it restarted, a few lines showed up on the screen for 10 seconds and then it was just a blinking cursor. Everytime I hard reboot my system now, it's just those lines for a few secs, then a blank screen with a blinking cursor. Nothing else. How can I fix this?

If it helps, I have a dual booted system with Windows 11 and Ubuntu on it. When it starts, it gives me a menu to choose from, which also has an option for ubuntu with advanced options, which has 4 different options. Can that help?
Is my OS gone? Do I have to reinstall it? Even if so, can I recover the data from my system first? Can these advanced Ubuntu options help?

Images for reference:

**The Options I get in the Ubuntu Advanced Options:**

[Ubuntu advanced Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Smpwf.jpg)

These are the options I get:

*Ubuntu, with Linux 5.0.95-generic, Ubuntu, with Linux 5.0.95-generic (with recovery mode), Ubuntu, with Linux 5.0.75-generic, Ubuntu, with Linux 5.0.75-generic (With recovery mode).*

**The lines that show up for a few seconds:**

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RsOM.jpg)

The error message:

[ 0.246343] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [_SB.PCIO.G
PPO. [ VGA], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20220331/dswload2-326)
0.246355] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name 1ookup/catalog 202203
31/psob.ject-220)
0.246359] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [__BB.PCIO.G
PPO.HDAU) [ [ AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20220331/dswload2-326)
0.246362] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name 100kup/catalog 202203
31/psob.ject-220)
0. 729645] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
0. 729657] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
0. 729693] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
0. 729727] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
0. 729765] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
0.729793] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
/dev/nvmeOn1p6: clean, 875612/4030464 files, 11290907/16111616 blocks
el
3.344494]

Comment: The kernel 5.0.x entries suggest that your system has been broken since long before even 20.04 (which uses kernel 5.4.x).

Comment: Oh! I see... but I installed Ubuntu 20.04... didn't have any prior versions!
Anyway, can I recover the data I had on this version so I can reinstall ubuntu? Or do you have any better workaround?

Comment: Download a 22.04 install image. Create a LiveUSB from that image. Boot the LiveUSB. Enter the "Try Ubuntu" environment. Recover your data onto some other media. Then use the same LiveUSB to wipe-and-reinstall a new release of Ubuntu.

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks a lot!

Just another doubt, can logging into the 5.0.x versions also help retrieve my data? Or will that result in data loss?

Comment: Sure, you can login to any working kernel version to retrieve your data. Data loss occurs during the reinstall step (and not even then if you select the correct option)..